# Why is this code working on a test website that I have but not on a local page or jfillde?

Tags: javascript

I have this code, and it is working fine on my test website but not in a browser as local (on my hdd) standalone page

Here it the code in jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9jdsvjfb/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(divId);
   ele.toggle();
}
</script>
    <style>
a:hover {
    color: purple;
}
a:active {
    color: purple;
}

</style>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="ConceptLevel1" href="javascript:toggleDiv(&#39;PktS/h+L5EeSqM/4hMH9JA==&#39;);"
    style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold; font-size:13pt">BGP -concept list</a>
    <br />
    <div style="padding-left:15px;" id="PktS/h+L5EeSqM/4hMH9JA==">
      <div>fds</div>
      <div>sdfdsfdfdsf</div>
      <div>sdfsdf</div>
      <div>gdhgf</div>
      <a class="ConceptLevel2" href="javascript:toggleDiv(&#39;SPrQVTbDx0WO6As2F+43tw==&#39;);"
      style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold; font-size:12pt">hfghg</a>
      <br />
      <div style="padding-left:15px;" id="SPrQVTbDx0WO6As2F+43tw==">
        <div>hfghgh</div>
        <div>fghfgh</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: When clicked the links should collapse the divs referred by the toggle function

Comment: Where and how are you monkey patching `toggle` to the native HTML(Div)Element?

Comment: I can not see any change the code is still not working 
@Teemu :sorry , the copy and paste did not work here, the fiddle has the correct IDs

Comment: @MiniMe There seems to be a bunch of updates, see https://jsfiddle.net/9jdsvjfb/5/ , it shows you an error in the console ("ele.toggle is not a function.")

Comment: I fixed your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9jdsvjfb/3/ look at the differences in the js pane.  You don't need the <script> tag and you needed to include the element in jQuery selector tags.

Comment: @ChrisAdams I don't disagree with you, but like I already commented to Roimer's answer, OP states "it is working fine on my test website". Obviously it shouldn't, but if they say so ...? That makes the question a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @guys thanks a lot. The script is part of an article that I post in Joomla. Not sure if the code interacts with the Joomla code in anyway (I am not a web programmer, I am just a network guy trying to give a functional format to an article) As I said the initial code works bus so does Chris' so if that works in bot Jfiddle and my web site I will go with that because next step is to use LocalStorage to save the status of these huge number of divs ..Not sure if I should use another post for that. Chris can you post your comment as an answer ?

Comment: Sorry for the many updates to that jfiddle, I have no idea how to delte them, to avoid confusions

Comment: You should give credit to @Roimer, his answer is essentially the same.  I would recommend investing a couple of days with a jQuery course: jQuery can return the status of any element and can be combined for very powerful UI.  You definitely don't need to use local storage to keep track of the DOM! Browse the examples at http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ to see how you can "write less, do more" and your life will be much easier.

Comment: Done. I am trying to save the toggle status of each element so it can be restored when the reader returns to my doc.  I am going to post a question about this, I am now able to read and set the status but I am not sure about how to recover the status ...thanks a lot for helping with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two problems here. First, Divs doesn't have a `toggle` function; I think you mean:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
  var ele = jQuery('#' + divId);
  ele.toggle();
}
```

The other problem is in the jsFiddle: since jsFiddle sends all Javascript wrapped inside a function (in windows.load) it is needed to define the function toggleDiv as a global variable, for it to be found when clicking the link:

```
window.toggleDiv = function (divId) {
  var ele = jQuery('#' + divId);
  ele.toggle();
}
```

Just a final note: It may be better if instead of embedding the Javascript insite the HMTL, you use events in order to bind the toggle function to the links' click event.

Comment: You're most likely right here, but on the other hand, OP says "it is working fine on my test website".